# Multiple fields with same key in query params (axios request)?

Tags: javascript, parameters, request, axios

So the backend (not under my control) requires a query string like this:

```
http://example.com/?foo=5&foo=2&foo=11
```

But `axios` uses a JS object to send the request params:

```js
axios.get('http://example.com/', { foo: 5 });
```

And obviously an object can't have multiple fields with the same key.

How can I send a request with multiple fields with the same key?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

From the [Request Config](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config) section of the axios documentation:

> ```js
>   // `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
>   // Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object
>   params: {
>     ID: 12345
>   },
> ```

To use this in a request, you would do

```js
const request = {
  params: {
    foo: [5, 2, 11]
  }
}
axios.get('http://example.com/', request);
```

The issue with using a plain object is that array parameters are added as

```
http://example.com/?foo[]=5&foo[]=2&foo[]=11
```

To make a request to a URL without the `[]`, use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("foo", 5);
params.append("foo", 2);
params.append("foo", 11);
var request = {
  params: params
};
axios.get('http://example.com/', request);
```

This will result in a request to

```
http://example.com/?foo=5&foo=2&foo=11
```

Answer (score 64):

In Axios request config, you can override params serialization and then use **QS NPM module** to serialize array with *repeat* mode

```
let params = { foo: [5, 2] }

axios.get('path/to/api/',{params}) // URL : https://path/to/api?foo[]=5&foo[]=2

let myAxios = axios.create({
    paramsSerializer: params => Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
})
myAxios.get('path/to/api/',{params}) // URL : https://path/to/api?foo=5&foo=2
```

Comment: The bad news is, this method causes colons to be escaped (not ideal for UTC time strings)

Comment: I used the `query-string` module which works similarly, but doesn't have a `repeat` option, but rather does this same behavior by default.

Comment: To avoid encoding values, one can pass the parameters like this `{ encode: false, arrayFormat: 'repeat' }`

Answer (score 18):

The correct answer with the latest axios version (in the year 2022) would be to set `indexes: null` in order to get `arrayFormat: 'repeat'`.

More info: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5058#issuecomment-1272107602

Example:

```
const {data} = await axios.get('https://postman-echo.com/get', {
  params: {
    a: ['b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  paramsSerializer: {
    indexes: null // by default: false
  }
});
```

> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'indices' }) ==> config.paramsSerializer.indexes = true // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c'

> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' }) ==> config.paramsSerializer.indexes = false// 'a[]=b&a[]=c' // **Default**

> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' }) ==> config.paramsSerializer.indexes = null// 'a=b&a=c'

> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'comma' }) ==> **not supported** // 'a=b,c'

Answer (score 4):

Update: Axios already supports this out of the box as of `axios@1.1.2`
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5058#issuecomment-1272107602

> @RNR1 Axios already supports this out of the box. By default, Axios encodes arrays in "bracket" format but supports 3 qs formats except "comma".

```
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'indices' }) ==> config.paramsSerializer.indexes = true // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c'
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' }) ==> config.paramsSerializer.indexes = false// 'a[]=b&a[]=c' // **Default**
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' }) ==> config.paramsSerializer.indexes = null// 'a=b&a=c'
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'comma' }) ==> **not supported** // 'a=b,c'
```

> So to encode in arrayFormat: 'repeat' you need to do the following:

```
  const {data} = await axios.get('https://postman-echo.com/get', {
    params: {
      a: ['b', 'c', 'd']
    },
    paramsSerializer: {
      indexes: null // by default: false
    }
  });
```

> Echo response:

```
{
  args: { a: [ 'b', 'c', 'd' ] },
  headers: {
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
    'x-forwarded-port': '443',
    host: 'postman-echo.com',
    'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-63409c06-5d9fc0344ceaf9715466e0e3',
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'user-agent': 'axios/1.1.0',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
  },
  url: 'https://postman-echo.com/get?a=b&a=c&a=d' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding more details to @nhydock accepted answer.
When you do

```
var request = {foo: [5, 2, 11] }
```

axios.get('http://example.com/', request);

For django application you can receive these as

```
self.request.query_params.getlist('foo')
```

also.

Answer (score -2):

> Disclaimer: I have never used Axios and couldn't find any reference in
>   the documentation. It is still worth a try. Personally, I would
>   implement it this way in a library.

It might also be possible to pass arrays as values for the parameter:

`axios.get('http://example.com/', { foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] });`

Comment: Sorry :( I've seen there's a `paramSerializer` in the process of building the URL, you might be able to tap in there and make it so it works with arrays too?

Comment: Yeah I'm currently using `query-string` package's `stringify()` function, but I'm hoping to find a different way. Probably doesn't exist though

Comment: You could send a PR to axios fixing this though :)

Answer (score -2):

If one uses the ready [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) the handling of multiple parameter values with the same name works with axios as well ... I guess the support for IE came in 2017 ... Works on Safari too, although the links claims that it might not ..

```
function getUrlParams(){
        // handles multiple param values with the same name
        var url_params = new URLSearchParams(); 

        if( window.location.toString().indexOf("?") != -1) {
           window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('#')[0]
              .replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function(m, key, value) {
              var attr = decodeURIComponent(key)
              var val = decodeURIComponent(value)
              url_params.append(attr,val);
           });
        } else {
           // create a default set of params - you might not need this one ...
           url_params = { some_param:"some_value" };
        }
        return url_params ;
     }


     function getBackEndData(url_params, back_end_url){
           // the replace is just a fancy way of converting front-end to back-end call
           return axios.get( back_end_url , { params: url_params } )
           .then(response => {
              return response.data ;
           })
           .catch(function(error) {
              return error.response ; 
              console.log(error.response.data);
           })
     }
```