# Axios get with param array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I create one get request with axios:

```
this.$axios.get('/cidade/',{
          params: {
            q: result,
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.cidades = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {

          // always executed
        });
```

but my result is an array [123asdas1,asdasd2312]  and when the axios excute the request he create that url:

```
http://localhost:8081/cidade/?q[]=5b9cfd0170607a2e968b0a1e&q[]=5b9cfd0170607a2e968b0a1d
```

so It's possible to remove the [] from q param? how?

tks

Comment: The way it’s doing it is the proper way to send a parameter array in a url. Your server should parse that to a single `q` param whose value is an array of ["5b9cfd0170607a2e968b0a1e", "5b9cfd010607a2e968b0a1d"]. Is your server not parsing the param that way? Because it should be. If not, then you should try to figure out why that is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple fields with same key in query params (axios request)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898009/multiple-fields-with-same-key-in-query-params-axios-request)

Answer (score 7):

When composing a query string where one field has multiple values (i.e. if it were an array), then there is no standard that says how it must be encoded in the query string, however most web servers accept this syntax:

```
http://localhost:8081/cidade/?q[]=value1&q[]=value2
```

which is why axios defaults to it. Check your web server to see if it is reading the parameter as an array correctly.

If you want to force it to be encoded in some other way, just convert the array to a string in whatever format you want and send it as a single value:

```js
this.$axios.get('/cidade/', {
  params: {
    q: JSON.stringify(result)
  }
})
```

```
http://localhost:8081/cidade/?q=[value1,value2]
```

(The `[` and `]` characters may be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).)

In general, this syntax cannot distinguish between the string `"[value1,value2]"` and the array `[value1, value2]`, so the web server will have to choose one or the other. Again, this is all dependent on your web server.