# Vue JS - Using URLSearchParams is showing me error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object and I need to pass it to the ajax request.

```
advanceSearch(e, field) { 
           
    this.searchString.push({
        [field] : e
    });

    let q = new URLSearchParams(this.searchString).toString();
    
    // this.searchTerm = e;
    http.get('projects/search/'+q)
    .then( ( response ) => {
        console.log( response )
    })
    .catch( ( error ) => {

    });
},
```

Here `thissearchString` is an array of object. I need to pass this array of object to the URL. So, I am using `URLSearchParams` but got this error message:

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URLSearchParams': The object must have a callable @@iterator property
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709142/best-way-to-pass-query-parameters-to-url-using-axios-in-vue

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me why that error message is showing? Is there any JS way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you not understand the function of URLSearchParams.
Here, what this function do:

```js
const paramsString = "myquery=value&topic=api"
const searchParams= new URLSearchParams(this.searchString) 
// Convert the string into a URLSearchParams, this allow multiples methods on it.
```

With that you can apply multiple function, the common is to use it like that:

```js
// const searchParams= new URLSearchParams(this.searchString) 
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

Output:
- ['myquery', 'value']
- ['topic', 'api']
```

Relative to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

If i see your code, you want exactly the opposite of that.

You can easly do that like that:

```js
const paramsString = {
 myquery: 'value',
 topic: 'api'
}

Object.entries(paramsString).map(params => `${params[0]}:${params[1]}`).join('&')
// Object entries define a value and a key. You map on that and got params[0] wich is a key and params[1] the value.
// In map you return a string and receive a array with ['key:value']
// You join all array to convert in a string and set a & between

output:
- 'myquery:value&topic:api'
```

With a array of object:

```js
const paramsString =  [{ id : 1 }, { brand : 'bata' }, { price : 123} ]

const result = paramsString
    .map((params) =>
        Object.entries(params).map(
            (keyValue) => `${keyValue[0]}:${keyValue[1]}`
        )
    )
    .join('&')
// You got each object on map
// Convert him to key & value like before and return a array with string
// Join each array with '&'
```

Comment: I have this type of array of object `let obj = [
    { id : 1 }, 
    { brand : 'bata' },
    { price : 123}
];`

Comment: @Shibbir I have updated the response with your array :)