# Axios Percent Encode on GET request

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request in Axios with what I believe are "percent encoded" parameters.  D

I am trying to call a URL that should resolve to:
`https://example.com/api/list?pageSize=15&statusFilters=%5B"DELETED"%2C"DRAFT"%5D`

Below is my code, however this resolves to `https://example.com/api/list?pageSize=15&statusFilters[]=LIVE&statusFilters[]=DRAFT` which for some bonkers reason returns a completely different set of results (not my API)

```
var params = {
  pageSize: 15,
  statusFilters: ["LIVE","DRAFT"]
}

return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    params,
    url: `${API_URL}${url}`,
})
```

Comment: Use JavaScript native's function [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function

Comment: How do I go about using that on the params?

Comment: Ah, now I get what is your problem. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898009/multiple-fields-with-same-key-in-query-params-axios-request) is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple fields with same key in query params (axios request)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898009/multiple-fields-with-same-key-in-query-params-axios-request)