# How setting query params in axios can break

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to set query params for a http get request. In the docs it mentions you can use the `params` property in the request config.

**1st**

```
const url = this.oAuthModel.api_url + this.oAuthModel.endpoint;

const config = {
    params: {
        "client_id": this.oAuthModel.clientId,
        "scope": this.oAuthModel.scopes,
        "redirect_uri": this.oAuthModel.returnUrl,
        "state": state
    }
}

return await axios.get(url, config)
```

When i try the above the request fails informing of an invalid client_id. However, im 100% certian im using the correct client_id value.

If i add the query params directly to the url like this it works.

**2nd**

```
const endpoint = `dialog/oauth?client_id=${this.oAuthModel.clientId}&scope=${this.oAuthModel.scopes}&redirect_uri=${this.oAuthModel.returnUrl}&state=${state}`;
return await axios.get(url + endpoint);
```

---

Can someone tell me why the first attempt at setting params fail but the second attempt setting params directly in the url works.

Comment: Where does the `this.oAuthModel.clientId` come from? If it comes from `env` make sure it's loaded.

Comment: Its not from env, it is loaded i console logged it and the correct value is present. 

It seems like axios is doing something strange when using param option.

Comment: I suggest checking browser console and see what exactly the erroneous request looks like. If needed, you can add your own param serializer. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43208627/4929038) SO answer